# PHPMailer connection error in using gmail smtp

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

I'm having error in using the PHPMailer in github. I tried to modify the ones on youtube and still not working

My error
[image: phpmailer error]

My code

[image]

PS: Changed the username/pw to sample

Comment: The DNS on your Server/PC is broken, PHPMailer can't resolve the domain smtp.gmail.com to an IP address. Fix the DNS issue and PHPMailer will work.

Comment: Yes you're right. Seems like my company's firewall is blocking any smtp connection. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

                $mail->IsSMTP();
                try {
                    $mail->Host = "mail.yourDomain.com"; 
                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;               
                    $mail->Username = "username"; 
                    $mail->Password = "pass";        
                    $mail->AddAddress($receiverMail, ''); 
                    $mail->SetFrom('test@yoerdomain.com', 'my company name'); 
                    $mail->Subject = 'subject';
                    $mail->AltBody = 'Alternate text'
                    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
                    $mail->ContentType = 'text/html';
                    $msg="<body style='text-align: right;direction: rtl'>"."your text body"."<br>< company name ></body></html>";
                    $mail->MsgHTML($msg);
                    $mail->Send();
}catch (phpmailerException $e) {
                        echo $e->errorMessage(); 
                    }
```

Comment: Didn't resolve the issue but my problem is my company's firewall not allowing any smtp connections. Thanks!